# Multiple actions on one keyboard shortcut in vscode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have multiple actions assigned to one keyboard shortcut in visual studio code?

For example:
Move cursor up x 3 set to "ctrl + w"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808371/how-can-i-run-multiple-commands-with-a-single-vs-code-keybinding-without-an-exte/75808372#75808372 -  you typically do not need an extension to run multiple commands with one shortcut as of vscode v1.77.

Answer (score 22):

It's possible with extensions like [Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.commands) [Note: Created by the post's author]

`settings.json`

```js
"commands.commands": {
    "down3": {
        "sequence": [
            "cursorDown",
            "cursorDown",
            "cursorDown",
        ],
    },
},
```

`keybindings.json`

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "down3",
},
```

---

Or with just `keybindings.json`

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "commands.run",
    "args": [
        "cursorDown",
        "cursorDown",
        "cursorDown"
    ]
},
```

Feature request to support [Macro like keybindings #871](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/871).

---

Although, for this particular example it's better to use the `built-in` command (to avoid any jumpiness):

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "down",
        "by": "line",
        "value": 3
    }
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

Answer (score 2):

I use the [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros):

in settings.json:

```json
"macros": {
    "showGit": ["workbench.view.scm", "git-graph.view"]
}
```

then in keybindings.json:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+g",
    "command": "showGit"
}
```