# Visual Studio Code: Keyboard shortcut for "Line Comment and Move down" combination

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way, how to assign keyboard shortcut to "Toggle Line Comment and then move cursor one line down?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009184/multiple-actions-on-one-keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode

Comment: Great! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the comment:

- istall [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)
- add to your `settings.json`:

```
    "multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "multiCommand.commentDown",
            "sequence": [
                "editor.action.addCommentLine",
                "cursorDown",
            ]
        },
    ],
```