# VS Code jump x lines up/down in any window/menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, key-bindings, hotkeys

In VS Code, is there a way to move the cursor x lines up/down in the **currently active** window or menu? I found a great post showing how it can be done for the text editor window ([Microsoft VS Code - Jump 10 lines vertically at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040925/microsoft-vs-code-jump-10-lines-vertically-at-once)),

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "up",
        "by": "line",
        "value": 10
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+down",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "down",
        "by": "line",
        "value": 10
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

but I'm trying to get it to work for any window or menu that is currently active, to make navigating with only the keyboard a little faster, such as in the Explorer window (Ctrl + Shift + E), in the Breadcrumb menu (Ctrl + Shift + .) or in the Quick Open menu (Ctrl + P).

Looking at the VS Code keybindings webpage (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), under the **'when' clause contexts** section it states *"If your key binding doesn't have a when clause, the key binding is globally available at all times."*, but when removing the *when* clause from the custom keybinding, it unfortunately still only seems to work in the text editor window, and not in any other window or menu.