# VS code keybinding/command to move the cursor 4-5 lines up

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code 1.56.2 and I want to add a keybinding that will move the cursor 4-5 lines up, but there isn't any pre-existing command for that. I've tried googling but I can't find any way to do this or add a custom command.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040925/microsoft-vs-code-jump-10-lines-vertically-at-once

Comment: you can also use [Select By Line Number](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-line-number)