# VSCode gotoLine shortcut acts as "enter" key also

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I hit the keyboard shortcut to gotoLine in vscode, it opens the drop down window. Once I type in the line number, I would like the keyboard shortcut that opened the gotoLine pallete, to also execute the gotoline and close the pallete.

For example I have tilde key mapped to gotoLine.

When I enter the line number, I would like it to behave such that when I hit tilde again, it acts as if I hit enter (not escape).

Is there a way I can do that with keymappings in vscode?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009184/multiple-actions-on-one-keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you mapped to the tilde, I don't know what kind of keyboard you are on, but on my keyboard the tilde <kbd>~</kbd>  is **shifted** on the same key as the backtick <kbd>`</kbd> so I used that below. But you could use whatever key you wish instead.

```
  {
    "key": "`",
    "command": "workbench.action.gotoLine",
    "when": "!inQuickOpen"

  },
  {
    "key": "`",
    "command": "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
  },

  // you may not care about disabling the default open quickOpen:gotoLine
  {
    "key": "ctrl+g",
    "command": "-workbench.action.gotoLine"
  }
```